My PC (Windows 11) is only listening on my local IP
I'm trying to set up a very basic FTP server to share files with a friend across the country. I tested it and I can login locally to the local IP address 127.0.0.1 port 21.
But when I try on a friend's network in my laptop to connect remotely it doesn't work on my server when it lists all the listening IPS it lists 127.0.0.1 and the other one is 168.x.x.x something neither are my actual local IP address which starts with 68.63.x.x.
I am relatively new to this I have done it before but I've never come across this particular issue I'm using Comcast Xfinity no VPN or anything like that no firewall just Windows defender.

Are you behind a CGNAT? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment. Which address is this remote user trying? 168.x.x.x is an intranet address

@Ramhound 168.x.x.x is "intranet"? I can't find any reference material for that

@JaromandaX I suppose Ramhound is assuming the OP meant 192.168.xxx.xxx. The assumption is likely correct.

@ChanganAuto - you know what happens when you assume?

@JaromandaX I know :) but I'm confident in this case.

@Ramhound I was assuming you were assuming. Other than that I assumed nothing.

@Ramhound are you referring to APIPA? APIPA is 169.254.x.x, AFAIK. Not sure if 168.x.x.x has a specified role.
